# Reset status bar tmux after exiting an ssh connection started within a tmux window

Tags: ssh, statusbar, reset, tmux

I tried many things but tmux seems to be very stubborn on this one.

When I start a tmux session in bash it shows

`0:bash*`

in my status bar. Then when I ssh to a server it gives me

`0:user@server:~*`

When I then exit the ssh session, the status bar does not revert to the previous

`0:bash*`, it just keeps the `0:user@server:~*`

which is annoying to me. I checked the man page, searched the internets, but hope the hive mind can assist me here.

This is all I have in my .tmux.conf,

```
set -g mouse on
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

`tmux -V` outputs `tmux 2.6`

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [unix.se] or [su].

Comment: Sure, do I have to make a new account there, or can I use my current stackoverflow account there too?

Comment: You won't have to create a completely new account there. It will let you sign in with your stackoverflow account.

Comment: Ok, asked the question over there https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/717129/reset-status-bar-tmux-after-exiting-an-ssh-connection-started-within-a-tmux-wind?noredirect=1#comment1359532_717129